# Paging GeoResults with Spring Data MongoDB using GeoPage

Tags: java, mongodb, geospatial, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am writing an LBS application using MongoDB's geospatial query functions and Spring Data MongoDB. Here is the code that uses a repository to query for the geo results:

```
GeoPage<RestaurantLocation> results = restaurantLocationRepository.findByLocationNear(point, distance, new PageRequest(0, 1));
```

I have 5 `RestaurantLocation` records (all within the distance) in my test MongoDB instance and I would expect this query to return only 1 record (page size is 1) but the returned `GeoPage` contains all 5 records.

In contrast, when I change my code to the following:

```
Page<RestaurantLocation> results = restaurantLocationRepository.findByLocationNear(point , distance, new PageRequest(0, 1));
```

The paging works as expected. It only returns 1 record but it is not a `GeoResult`.

What I want is the paginated `GeoResult` of `RestaurantLocation`.

Comment: Did you find the answer for your question? I am also facing the same issue